# Alert Scrollbar - Ionic

Tags: ionic, mobile, alert

Boa Tarde

Gostaria de saber como tiro o scrollbar do alert
presentConfirm() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Saindo da Aplicação',
      message: 'Tem certeza que deseja sair?  ',

```
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'CANCELAR',
      role: 'CANCELAR',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'SIM',
      handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

}